# How to add colors to categorical groups in a D3 directional force layout diagram?

Tags: d3.js, colors, nodes, force-layout

I am trying to apply color fill to my circle nodes in the layout. The problem is that my nodes get doubled in two groups. In one group the nodes are properly linked but the color is the same, in the other group the nodes are properly colored but not linked. http://jsfiddle.net/akszila/yodwt3bm/

```
 // Compute the distinct nodes from the links.

links.forEach(function(link) {
        link.source = nodes[link.source] || (nodes[link.source] = {name: link.source, group: link.group});
      link.target = nodes[link.target] || (nodes[link.target] = {name: link.target, group: link.group});
    });

var color = d3.scale.category10();

var width = 960,
    height = 500;

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .nodes(d3.values(nodes))
    .links(links)
    .size([width, height])
    .linkDistance(30)
    .charge(-100)
    .on("tick", tick)
    .start();

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

// Per-type markers, as they don't inherit styles.
svg.append("defs").selectAll("marker")
    .data(["oszt"])
    .enter().append("marker")
    .attr("id", function (d) {
    return d;
})
    .attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
    .attr("refX", 16)
    .attr("refY", -1.5)
    .attr("markerWidth", 6)
    .attr("markerHeight", 6)
    .attr("orient", "auto")
    .append("path")
    .attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5");

var path = svg.append("g").selectAll("path")
    .data(force.links())
    .enter().append("path")
    .attr("class", function (d) {
    return "link " + d.type;
})
    .attr("marker-end", function (d) {
    return "url(#" + d.type + ")";
});

var circle = svg.append("g").selectAll("circle")
    .data(force.nodes())
    .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("r", 7)
    .style("fill", function (d) {
    return color(d.group);
})
    .call(force.drag);



var text = svg.append("g").selectAll("text")
    .data(force.nodes())
    .enter().append("text")
    .attr("x", 8)
    .attr("y", ".31em")
    .text(function (d) {
    return d.name;
})
    .style("fill", function (d) {
    return color(d.group);
});




// Use elliptical arc path segments to doubly-encode directionality.
function tick() {
    path.attr("d", linkArc);
    circle.attr("transform", transform);
    text.attr("transform", transform);
}

function linkArc(d) {
    var dx = d.target.x - d.source.x,
        dy = d.target.y - d.source.y,
        dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
    return "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y + "A" + dr + "," + dr + " 0 0,1 " + d.target.x + "," + d.target.y;
}

function transform(d) {
    return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
}
```

If I modify 
    `var force = d3.layout.force()
    .nodes(d3.values(nodes))
    .links(links)
    .size([width, height])
    .linkDistance(30)
    .charge(-100)
    .on("tick", tick)
    .start();`

to `var force = d3.layout.force()
    .nodes(nodes)
    .links(links)
    .size([width, height])
    .linkDistance(30)
    .charge(-100)
    .on("tick", tick)
    .start();`
the result is the nodes are properly colored but not linked and there are no duplicates fortunately.